# How to resolve Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or receiver with intent filter can't be installed on Android 12+

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, google-play-console, android-12

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher.
> See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

I already added `android:exported="true"` in activity, service and receiver which having intent-filter. i changed the combination android:exported="true"/"false" and uploaded many times but still getting the same error message.

how to get rid of this issue.